# Movie about some cowboys who travel into the future (to our time)

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I watch this film several times when I was a kid but now I can only remember a few details.

I know it was about some cowboys who travel into the future. I think it happens because the thunder hits their house or something near them. Then next thing they are in the future (our time). One of the first things they see is a plane in the sky. I can't quite remember what happens after that. I think at the end they go back to their own time (again with the thunder), or at least try, but there's some conflict, maybe one of them decides to stay behind or something. I know it's very vague, any idea what it could be?

Comment: Can you update your profile or tell us *when* you were a kid. It'll be easier for people to eliminate films based on the release date :)

Comment: I think I was watching it in the second half of the 80s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outlaws. It was a pilot TV movie on CBS in 1986. It was followed by just a few episodes of a series before being canceled..

Read more at Wikipedia: [Outlaws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlaws_%281986_TV_series%29)